# Writing multiple queries

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite

I have written the query given below for fetching data with two parameters. Can you suggest the correct SQL syntax for this purpose.

SQL query:

```
FMResultSet *resultOfDesiredCuisine = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"select * from dishes where cuisineId IN (select cuisineId from cuisines where  Lower(cuisineName) like %@) and 
        categoryID IN \"(select categoryID from categories where Lower(categoryName) like %@)",cuisineName,categoryName];
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not work white the `%@` syntax but uses `?`

```
FMResultSet *resultOfDesiredCuisine = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM dishes WHERE cuisineId IN (SELECT cuisineId FROM cuisines WHERE LOWER(cuisineName) like ?) AND 
        categoryID IN (SElECT categoryID FROM categories WHERE LOWER(categoryName) LIKE ?)", cuisineName, categoryName];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response .just for info sake categoryName and cuisineName are strings . sorry to say that but its still not working.

Comment: Whats the error? and are you sure that the query is returning rows?

Comment: anyways thanks a lot . i have got the correct answer . we have to break the string and then process.